# express-http-proxy Error Handling

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

I have set up a local proxy server using node, express and express-http-proxy, which redirects the requests to a remote backend, which is only available via VPN. This works well when the VPN connection is established. However, when there is no vpn connection i am getting this error:

```
    _http_outgoing.js:346
        throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
        ^

    Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
        at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
        at /path/to/my/project/proxy/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:152:9
        at next (/path/to/my/project/proxy/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:150:14)
        at SendStream.error (/path/to/my/project/proxy/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:74:37)
        at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
        at SendStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
        at SendStream.error (/path/to/my/project/proxy/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:147:51)
        at SendStream.onStatError (/path/to/my/project/proxy/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:248:48)
        at /path/to/my/project/proxy/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:320:26
        at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

My Proxy setup is:

```
    app.use('/the/api', proxy('the.domain.behind.vpn:8026', {
        timeout : 4000,

        forwardPath : function(req, res){
            console.log(nodeUrl.parse(req.url).path);

            return "/the/api" + nodeUrl.parse(req.url).path;
        },

        intercept : function(rsp, data, req, res, callback){
            data = data.toString("utf8").replace(/http\:\/\/the\.domain\.behind\.vpn\:8026/g, "http://localhost:61000");
            callback(null, data);
        },

        decorateRequest : function(proxyReq, originalReq){
            if(proxyReq.method === "HEAD"){
                proxyReq.method = "GET";
            }

            return proxyReq;
        }
    }));
```

What causes this error, and how can i catch it?